# Error with expanding divs

Tags: javascript, html

I have encountered a problem with expandable divs. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div><a href="javascript:showHide('expand');">more...</a></div>
<div class="expand" style="display:none">
  YO DAWgGG
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function showHide(elementid){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("expand").style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementsByClassName("expand").style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("expand").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  </script>
```

It says that expand is undefined. But I don't see why. What am I doing wrong? Same code works if i use an ID but i need this for more than one div.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[0]`

Comment: What works? You can only use one ID once per page, if I get you.

Comment: Like this?
(document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[0].style.display == 'none')

It's not working :(

The code works if i use this on a element instea of a class, but the problem is that i need to use the code on more than one div. Thx for helping me figure this out

Comment: @AlexCassady getElementsByClassName()  doesnt return an Array. It is a HTMLCollection. Though you could use the square bracket notation, it is not an Array and none of the array specific methods can be used directly on them

Comment: @smuckert I update my answer with a sample having multiple links

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[0]` as `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of object.

```js
function showHide(el){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

```html
<div><a href="javascript:showHide('expand');">more...</a></div>
<div class="expand" style="display:none">
  YO DAWgGG
</div>
```

Based on the existing markup. I recommend to use `document.querySelectorAll`, and instead of setting an elements style, toggle its class.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
  })
}
```

```css
.expand {
  display: none;
}

.expand.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><a class="link" href="#">more...</a></div>
<div class="expand">
  YO DAWgGG 1111
</div>


<div><a class="link" href="#">more...</a></div>
<div class="expand">
  YO DAWgGG 222
</div>


<div><a class="link" href="#">more...</a></div>
<div class="expand">
  YO DAWgGG 333
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns you a HTMLCollection and not a HTMLElement and hence you cant use .style on the collection.

So, if you need to apply some styling on all elements of the collection, you need to iterate over and apply.

Here is what you could do.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".more");

  [].forEach.call(anchors, (anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      let parent = event.target.parentNode;
      let ele = parent.querySelector(".expand");
      if (ele.style.display == 'none') {
        ele.style.display = '';
      } else {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<div><a class="more" href="#">more...</a>
  <div class="expand" style="display:none">
    YO DAWgGG
  </div>
</div>
<div><a class="more" href="#">more-2-...</a>
  <div class="expand" style="display:none">
    YO DAWgGG-2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you wizards! That solved my problem but caused another one for me. I'm trying to make it so only the one div you choose to expand (click on)  opens up, not all divs within the same class. How do I achieve this? Sorry this might be confusing for you guys. Do I put id's instead and repeat the code for every ID?

Comment: if you want to have a similar functionality with more links. I would do it slightly different. I have updated the code snippet. It should work if you have one / if you have many more links on the page.

Comment: All you need is to group your more anchor link and the expand section together, so We know which expand section needs to be shown. It binds the event to all anchors where more functionality is needed.